# php - How to solve this setcookie issues

Tags: php

Here is the web structure of my page:

```
01.<?php // rnlogout.php
02.include_once 'rnheader.php';
03.echo "<h3>Log out</h3>";
04. 
05.if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
06.{
07.    destroySession(); // report error here!!!!!!
08.    echo "You have been logged out. Please
09.    <a href='index.php'>click here</a> to refresh the screen.";
10.}
11.else echo "You are not logged in";
12.?>

function destroySession()
{
    $_SESSION=array();

    if (session_id() != "" || isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-2592000, '/');

    session_destroy();
}

01.<?php // rnheader.php
02.include 'rnfunctions.php';
03.session_start();
04. 
05.if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
06.{
07.    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
08.    $loggedin = TRUE;
09.}
10.else $loggedin = FALSE;
11. 
12.echo "<html><head><title>$appname";
13.if ($loggedin) echo " ($user)";
14. 
15.echo "</title></head><body><font face='verdana' size='2'>"; // called first!!!!!
16.echo "<h2>$appname</h2>";
17. 
18.if ($loggedin)
19.{
20.    echo "<b>$user</b>:
21.         <a href='rnmembers.php?view=$user'>Home</a> |
22.         <a href='rnmembers.php'>Members</a> |
23.         <a href='rnfriends.php'>Friends</a> |
24.         <a href='rnmessages.php'>Messages</a> |
25.         <a href='rnprofile.php'>Profile</a> |
26.         <a href='rnlogout.php'>Log out</a>";
27.}
28.else
29.{
30.    echo "<a href='index.php'>Home</a> |
31.         <a href='rnsignup.php'>Sign up</a> |
32.         <a href='rnlogin.php'>Log in</a>";
33.}
34.?>
```

Please take a look the line 07

```
destroySession(); // report error here
```

Based on the php manual, `http://us2.php.net/setcookie`
cookies must be sent before any output from your script. Here the `rnheader.php`
call echo even before the setcookie call in function destroySession.

So how do I change the page structure to fix this problem?

```
The error message is as follows:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\LPMJ_examples\robinsnest\rnheader.php:12) in C:\xampp\htdocs\LPMJ_examples\robinsnest\rnfunctions.php on line 41
```

Thank you

Comment: We can't tell you how to change the structure, because we don't know that `rnheader.php` does. As a general rule, put all header/cookie emitting commands before anything is output.

Comment: @Vadim i can tell with a quick look at line 3 (without looking into rnheader.php) that the error is `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` (and so on ;) )

Comment: Hello Vadim,

I have attached the error message inside the original post.

thank you

Comment: Hello Pekka,

I have posted the rnheader.php inside the original question.

thank you

Comment: ok then the reason that you output some information , after this you try to send again headers with setcookie() function, try to make the proper management before echoing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the [PHP-Manual :: Output Control](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/ref.outcontrol.php)

if you don't want to rewrite your scripts use output control functions (as mention above)

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once 'rmheader.php';
echo '<h3>Log Out</h3>';

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    destroySession(); // report error here!!!!!!
    echo "You have been logged out. Please <a href='index.php'>click here</a> to refresh the screen.";
} else {
    echo "You are not logged in";
}

function destroySession()
{
    $_SESSION=array();

    if (session_id() != "" || isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-2592000, '/');

    session_destroy();
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function destroySession() has to be set before you call it, so place the defined function at the top after the `<?php` which would work.